# Issues with Google Map - Greyed Out

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am loading Google Map with some customised markers in my HTML. However, the map gets greyed out when the page is loaded. Other than the greyed out box, it works fine as i can move around within the window box and when i maximise the map and minimise again, the map works like it should.

I read online that it might be due to bootstrap 3 and the following code will help solve the issue. but i have been adding this code around the google map script but it does resolve the problem. Is this the solution? and where should i add this?

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
});
```

My HTML Codes are as follows and the script to load the map is at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Title -->
<title>Tagora.travel</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<!-- Default stylesheets-->
<link href="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Template specific stylesheets-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:400i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="assets/lib/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/lib/et-line-font/et-line-font.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Main stylesheet and color file-->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="color-scheme" href="assets/css/colors/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".onpage-navigation" data-offset="60">
<main>
  <!-- Loading Gif-->
  <div class="page-loader">
    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <!-- navbar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="Tagora.travel.html"><img src="assets/images/tagoralogo.png" alt="Tagora Logo"></a>

        <div id="search-form" >
            <form method="get" action="#">
              <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Search';" />
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="Tagora.travel.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Cities</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="bali.html">Bali</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Bandung</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Komodo Islands</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Gili Islands</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Yogyakarta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Nusa Tenggara</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html" >About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


<div class="main">
    <!-- About Us Picture with Quote-->

      <section id="modpictureitinerary" class="module-small bg-dark-60 shop-page-header" data-background="assets/images/bali.jpg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
              <h1 class="module-title font-alt">Bali</h1>
              <div class="module-subtitle font-serif">Bali is a living postcard, an Indonesian paradise that feels like a fantasy. Soak up the sun on a stretch of fine white sand, or commune with 
                the tropical creatures as you dive along coral ridges or the colorful wreck of a WWII war ship. On shore, the lush jungle shelters stone temples 
                and mischievous monkeys.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

     <!-- Specially Crafted Quote--> 

      <section class="module-itinerary">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

            <div class="font-serif operator-name">
              Crafted by <br>
              <b><span class="large-text">Di Bali Tour</span></b><br>
              Est. Since 2008
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

            <div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow572" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
              <ul id="gUjYoJi" class="TA_links mnhoDbKF8">
              <li id="ps2SrlKHA" class="nLHVd5g">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
              </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="module-itinerary">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-70">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs font-alt font-nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#itinerary" data-toggle="tab">Itinerary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#data-sheet" data-toggle="tab">Inclusions & Exclusions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reviews" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Location" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="itinerary">
                  <h3><b>Best of Bali (Private Tour)</b></h3>
                  <h4>Want to see the best bits of Bali in just one day? This private full-day tour includes a visit to Batuan temple, the UNESCO-listed Tegalalang rice terraces and the Ubud Art Villages. 
                    That’s not all: you’ll also get chance to learn about Luwak coffee and other Balinese coffee and tea, jump into the Tegenungan waterfall and shop for hand-made Balinese arts and crafts. All that, plus hotel pick-up and private transportation!
                  </h4>

                  <h3><b>Highlights</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Full-day private ‘Best of Bali’ tour from Ubud</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Visit Batuan temple and the Tegalalang rice terraces</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Cool off with a swim at Tegenungan waterfall</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Tour a coffee plantation</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Discover Balinese art and handicrafts in the Ubud Art Villages</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Great value tour includes hotel pick-up and round-trip transport</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>This private tour can be customized to your interests</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                  <h3><b>What You Can Expect</b></h3>
                  <h4>Meet your driver at your Bali hotel and begin your Best of Bali tour with a visit to Batuan Temple. Marvel at the beautiful Hindu temple as you learn its spiritual significance and points out the magnificent architecture and unique black palm roof. Next, visit Tegenungan Waterfall, where you can cool off with a swim beneath the falls or even brave a jump from the top of the 49-foot (15-meter) high falls. Continue north to Tegalalang to marvel at the UNESCO-listed rice terraces, one of Bali’s most photographed sights. Learn about the pioneering ‘subak’ system – the Balinese cooperative irrigation system – for which the terraces are known, as you admire the views over the rice paddies. After lunch (own expense), discover Indonesia’s world famous Luwak coffee at a local coffee plantation. Learn about the unusual method of producing the coffee, which involves the coffee berries being eaten and defecated by Asian palm civets, then collecting the part-digested beans from the forest floor. After sampling the other coffees and teas made at the plantation, perhaps opt to taste a Luwak coffee too (extra cost). In the afternoon, indulge your creative side with a visit to the Ubud Art Villages and discover the vibrant traditions of Balinese arts and handicrafts. Visit the woodcarving village of Mas, admire the fine Silver Filigree jewelry made in Celuk and watch a Batik painting demonstration in Tohpati Village. Finally, after an action-packed full-day itinerary, finish your tour with drop-off at your hotel.
                  </h4>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="data-sheet">
                    <h3><b>Inclusions</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Hotel pickup and drop-off in Ubud, Canggu, Seminyak, Legian, Kuta, Tuban, Jimbaran, Sanur, Denpasar, Tanjung Benoa, or Nusa Dua area</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Transport by private air-conditioned vehicle</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>English speaking driver (who will accompany you all day)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>All entrance fees as per itinerary</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Fuel fees</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Taxes</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                    <h3><b>Exclusions</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Food and drinks (available to purchase)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Gratuities (optional)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Personal expenses</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="reviews">
                    <div id="TA_selfserveprop109" class="TA_selfserveprop">
                        <ul id="SCyvxMFVI8X" class="TA_links HMIUYNM8Hl">
                        <li id="HH0xKeUSG" class="sXdLmWPfG">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="Location">
                    <section id="map-section">
                        <div id="map" ></div>
                    </section>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </section>


</div> 
    <!-- Footer-->

    <hr class="divider-d">
    <footer class="footer bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="copyright font-alt">&copy; 2017&nbsp;<a href="index.html">Tagora.travel</a>, All Rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="footer-social-links"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-up"><a href="#totop"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a></div>
</main>

<!--  JavaScripts   -->
<script src="assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/wow/dist/wow.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/simple-text-rotator/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=572&amp;locationId=6894357&amp;lang=en_SG&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=109&amp;locationId=6894357&amp;lang=en_SG&amp;rating=false&amp;nreviews=4&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=false&amp;iswide=true
&amp;border=false&amp;display_version=2"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=AIzaSyAweoP_TE8ov0X6TsaozZdfWQLAvpJIQZQ"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  var locations = [
    ['Bali Coffee Plantation', -8.703186, 115.212971, 4],
    ['Ubud Art Market', -8.507060, 115.262597, 5],
    ['Tegenungan Waterfall', -8.575291, 115.288575, 3],
    ['Tegalalang Rice Terrace', -8.434040, 115.279257, 2],
    ['Batuan Temple', -8.581871, 115.276005, 1]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -8.409518, 115.188916),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

</script>


</html>
```

Relevant CSS properties are as follows

```
#map-section {
position: relative;
height: 450px;
width: 100%;

}

#map {
height: 400px;
width: 450px;
overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following little snippet suggests `jQuery` is used but as there is no reference to `jQuery` in the tags associated with this question I used vanilla javascript below.

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
});
```

To use the google `resize` method you need to listen for window resize events - either by `window.onresize` or `window.addEventListener('resize'...`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var locations = [
    ['Bali Coffee Plantation', -8.703186, 115.212971, 4],
    ['Ubud Art Market', -8.507060, 115.262597, 5],
    ['Tegenungan Waterfall', -8.575291, 115.288575, 3],
    ['Tegalalang Rice Terrace', -8.434040, 115.279257, 2],
    ['Batuan Temple', -8.581871, 115.276005, 1]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -8.409518, 115.188916),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng( locations[i][1], locations[i][2] ),
      title:locations[i][0],/* assign the title - will be shown in infowindow onclick */
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
        infowindow.setContent( this.title );
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }.bind( marker ) );/* bind event listener to this marker*/
  }

  /* bind an event listener to window resize to then trigger the google map resize method */
  window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );
  },false);

</script>
```

---

After commenting out the assets not available to me to give the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Title -->
<title>Tagora.travel</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<!-- Default stylesheets-->
<!--
<link href="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->


<!-- Template specific stylesheets-->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:400i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

<!--
<link href="assets/lib/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/lib/et-line-font/et-line-font.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->


<!-- Main stylesheet and color file-->
<!--
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="color-scheme" href="assets/css/colors/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->


 </head>

 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".onpage-navigation" data-offset="60">
<main>
  <!-- Loading Gif-->
  <div class="page-loader">
    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <!-- navbar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="Tagora.travel.html"><img src="assets/images/tagoralogo.png" alt="Tagora Logo"></a>

        <div id="search-form" >
            <form method="get" action="#">
              <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Search';" />
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="Tagora.travel.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Cities</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="bali.html">Bali</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Bandung</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Komodo Islands</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Gili Islands</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Yogyakarta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Nusa Tenggara</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html" >About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


<div class="main">
    <!-- About Us Picture with Quote-->

      <section id="modpictureitinerary" class="module-small bg-dark-60 shop-page-header" data-background="assets/images/bali.jpg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
              <h1 class="module-title font-alt">Bali</h1>
              <div class="module-subtitle font-serif">Bali is a living postcard, an Indonesian paradise that feels like a fantasy. Soak up the sun on a stretch of fine white sand, or commune with 
                the tropical creatures as you dive along coral ridges or the colorful wreck of a WWII war ship. On shore, the lush jungle shelters stone temples 
                and mischievous monkeys.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

     <!-- Specially Crafted Quote--> 

      <section class="module-itinerary">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

            <div class="font-serif operator-name">
              Crafted by <br>
              <b><span class="large-text">Di Bali Tour</span></b><br>
              Est. Since 2008
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

            <div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow572" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
              <ul id="gUjYoJi" class="TA_links mnhoDbKF8">
              <li id="ps2SrlKHA" class="nLHVd5g">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
              </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="module-itinerary">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-70">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs font-alt font-nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#itinerary" data-toggle="tab">Itinerary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#data-sheet" data-toggle="tab">Inclusions & Exclusions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reviews" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Location" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="itinerary">
                  <h3><b>Best of Bali (Private Tour)</b></h3>
                  <h4>Want to see the best bits of Bali in just one day? This private full-day tour includes a visit to Batuan temple, the UNESCO-listed Tegalalang rice terraces and the Ubud Art Villages. 
                    That’s not all: you’ll also get chance to learn about Luwak coffee and other Balinese coffee and tea, jump into the Tegenungan waterfall and shop for hand-made Balinese arts and crafts. All that, plus hotel pick-up and private transportation!
                  </h4>

                  <h3><b>Highlights</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Full-day private ‘Best of Bali’ tour from Ubud</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Visit Batuan temple and the Tegalalang rice terraces</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Cool off with a swim at Tegenungan waterfall</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Tour a coffee plantation</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Discover Balinese art and handicrafts in the Ubud Art Villages</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Great value tour includes hotel pick-up and round-trip transport</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>This private tour can be customized to your interests</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                  <h3><b>What You Can Expect</b></h3>
                  <h4>Meet your driver at your Bali hotel and begin your Best of Bali tour with a visit to Batuan Temple. Marvel at the beautiful Hindu temple as you learn its spiritual significance and points out the magnificent architecture and unique black palm roof. Next, visit Tegenungan Waterfall, where you can cool off with a swim beneath the falls or even brave a jump from the top of the 49-foot (15-meter) high falls. Continue north to Tegalalang to marvel at the UNESCO-listed rice terraces, one of Bali’s most photographed sights. Learn about the pioneering ‘subak’ system – the Balinese cooperative irrigation system – for which the terraces are known, as you admire the views over the rice paddies. After lunch (own expense), discover Indonesia’s world famous Luwak coffee at a local coffee plantation. Learn about the unusual method of producing the coffee, which involves the coffee berries being eaten and defecated by Asian palm civets, then collecting the part-digested beans from the forest floor. After sampling the other coffees and teas made at the plantation, perhaps opt to taste a Luwak coffee too (extra cost). In the afternoon, indulge your creative side with a visit to the Ubud Art Villages and discover the vibrant traditions of Balinese arts and handicrafts. Visit the woodcarving village of Mas, admire the fine Silver Filigree jewelry made in Celuk and watch a Batik painting demonstration in Tohpati Village. Finally, after an action-packed full-day itinerary, finish your tour with drop-off at your hotel.
                  </h4>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="data-sheet">
                    <h3><b>Inclusions</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Hotel pickup and drop-off in Ubud, Canggu, Seminyak, Legian, Kuta, Tuban, Jimbaran, Sanur, Denpasar, Tanjung Benoa, or Nusa Dua area</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Transport by private air-conditioned vehicle</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>English speaking driver (who will accompany you all day)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>All entrance fees as per itinerary</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Fuel fees</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Taxes</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                    <h3><b>Exclusions</b></h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li><h4>Food and drinks (available to purchase)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Gratuities (optional)</h4></li>
                      <li><h4>Personal expenses</h4></li>
                    </ul> 

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="reviews">
                    <div id="TA_selfserveprop109" class="TA_selfserveprop">
                        <ul id="SCyvxMFVI8X" class="TA_links HMIUYNM8Hl">
                        <li id="HH0xKeUSG" class="sXdLmWPfG">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="Location">
                    <section id="map-section">
                        <div id="map" ></div>
                    </section>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </section>


</div> 
    <!-- Footer-->

    <hr class="divider-d">
    <footer class="footer bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="copyright font-alt">&copy; 2017&nbsp;<a href="index.html">Tagora.travel</a>, All Rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="footer-social-links"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-up"><a href="#totop"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a></div>
</main>

<!--  JavaScripts   -->
<!--
<script src="assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/wow/dist/wow.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/simple-text-rotator/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
-->
<script src="//www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=572&amp;locationId=6894357&amp;lang=en_SG&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
<script src="//www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=109&amp;locationId=6894357&amp;lang=en_SG&amp;rating=false&amp;nreviews=4&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=false&amp;iswide=true&amp;border=false&amp;display_version=2"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAweoP_TE8ov0X6TsaozZdfWQLAvpJIQZQ"></script>


<style>
    #map{
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var locations = [
    ['Bali Coffee Plantation', -8.703186, 115.212971, 4],
    ['Ubud Art Market', -8.507060, 115.262597, 5],
    ['Tegenungan Waterfall', -8.575291, 115.288575, 3],
    ['Tegalalang Rice Terrace', -8.434040, 115.279257, 2],
    ['Batuan Temple', -8.581871, 115.276005, 1]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -8.409518, 115.188916),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng( locations[i][1], locations[i][2] ),
      title:locations[i][0],/* assign the title - will be shown in infowindow onclick */
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
        infowindow.setContent( this.title );
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }.bind( marker ) );/* bind event listener to this marker*/
  }

  /* bind an event listener to window resize to then trigger the google map resize method */
  window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );
  },false);

</script>
</html>
```

One thing to note is the lack of closing `</body>` tag!

[image: screenshot of working code]

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and helping. Have added your script as you have suggested. However, it does not solve the problem though. the googlemap is still greyed out.

Comment: hmmz... this is really peculiar. it is still not working. Thought it might be the other css or javascript in the work folder that might be interfering and since it works for you, so i open a new standalone html file and copied your codes that you have used in. But i am getting a white space at where the map should be instead. not even the greyed out box. But no worries @RamRaider, you have been absolutely helpful in resolving this. really appreciate it.